# Display context menu when right-clicking only in specific GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, contextmenu

I have a GridView with multiple columns. I would like to display a ContextMenu only when an item in a specific menu is right-clicked on. Here's what I have so far:

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn>
        <!-- Show context menu for this column --> 
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>

    <GridViewColumn>
        <!-- Do not show context menu for this column -->
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```

I tried adding a `GridViewColumn.ContextMenu` between the `<GridViewColumn></GridViewColumn>` tags but that does not seem to exist. I also tried adding it inside the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` and `DataTemplate` without any luck.

Any suggestions on how I can have a `ContextMenu` for a specific column?c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add it inside the first child of `DataTemplate` (ie, it needs to be the child of a `FrameworkElement`).

```
<GridViewColumn>
    <!-- Show context menu for this column --> 
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>    
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Menu Item" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>    
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks -- that worked. I needed everything inside `DataTemplate` to be wrapped inside a `Grid` tag and also forgot the `ContextMenuService.ContextMenu` tag

Comment: You can also use a `DockPanel` or a `StackPanel` instead of a `Grid`, as long as it derives from `FrameworkElement`.  All depends on how you want the cell to display itself.